# Incrementing Operator in Foreach Loop for Pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm using CodeIgniter Pagination class to paginate my data 10 rows per page. I'm using foreach loop for that.

My problem is, the loop incrementing operator is reset back to 1 in the second, third & next pagination pages.

Page 1 screenshot [dummy data only]:
[image: dummy data only]

Page 2 screenshot [dummy data only]:
[image: dummy data only]

Page 3 screenshot [dummy data only]:
[image: dummy data only]

My controller:

```
<?php

class Mypagination extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){

        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = '/codeigniter/index.php/mypagination/index/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('tracking')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 10;

        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['query'] = $this->db->get('tracking', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->load->view('mypagination_view', $data);

    }
}
```

My view:

```
<?php

$i = 1;

foreach($query->result() as $row){
    echo $i++ . ') ';
echo $row->name . ' - ' . $row->email;
echo '<br>';
}

echo $this->pagination->create_links();

?>
```

I want that incrementing operator to continue in the next pagination pages like 11,12,13... in the second page. 21,22,23 in the third page...

How to fix this?

Sorry if this is too basic question. I'm just new with CodeIgniter and PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view :

```
$links = $this->pagination->create_links();
$i = 1 + $this->pagination->cur_page*$this->pagination->per_page;

foreach($query->result() as $row){
   echo $i++ . ') ';
   echo $row->name . ' - ' . $row->email;
   echo '<br>';
}

echo $links;
```

and you're cool.

Also, i'd recommend you use less echo, and only for php parts of your templating. For example, your code could be reformatted like this:

```
<?php $links = $this->pagination->get_links(); ?>

<ol start="<?php echo 1 + $this->pagination->cur_page*$this->pagination->per_page; ?>" >
<?php foreach($query->result() as $row) : ?>
   <li><?php echo $row->name . ' - ' . $row->email; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>

<?php echo $links; ?>
```

Looks cleaner now, i think.

Comment: Thanks. But the $i = 1 + $this->pagination->cur_page*$this->pagination->per_page; didn't work for me @ Андрей Почекуев.

Comment: Edited. Should work now. Problem was, pagination didn't get its current page until you use `create_links()` method.

Comment: `($this->pagination->cur_page-1)*$this->pagination->per_page` obviously.

Comment: @Eternal1 in my case 
20 rows return in my result per page
 
`$i= ($this->pagination->cur_page-1)*$this->pagination->per_page;
foreach($query->result() as $row){
   echo $i++;}`

starts my count from 0 on the first page, but from 2 its been working fine 

so i analyze the problem ... when i put `++i`  it started working fine

Answer (score 0):

Do you use sessions? Perhaps something like this:

```
<?php

$i = $this->session->userdata('increment') ? $this->session->userdata('increment') : 1;

foreach($query->result() as $row){
  echo $i++ . ') ';
  echo $row->name . ' - ' . $row->email;
  echo '<br>';
}

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
$this->session->set_userdata('increment', $i);

?>
```

Comment: @ Mudshark I'm not using session.